# Approximation of integrable function by a step function

Tags: calculus, probability, convergence-divergence

For the following : $\Omega = [0,1)$, $I_{k,n} = [k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]$ for $k=0$ to $k=2^n-1$, $F_n = \sigma(I_{k,n}, 0\leq k < 2^n)$

Let f be an integrable function on $\Omega$. I have already shown that

$g_n = \mathbb{E}[f|F_n] = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 2^n\mathbb{E}[f\mathbb{1}_{I_{k,n}}]\mathbb{1}_{I_{k,n}} $

Thus $g_n$ is a step function and I want to prove that it converges in $L_1$ toward f. Unfortunately I have some problems to finish the calculus.

$\mathbb{E} [ |\mathbb{E}[f|F_n] - f| ] = \int_0^1 |\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 2^n\mathbb{E}[f\mathbb{1}_{I_{k,n}}]\mathbb{1}_{I_{k,n}}(x) - f(x)|dx  $

$= \int_0^1 |\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 2^n\int_{I_{k,n}}f(y)dy\mathbb{1}_{I_{k,n}}(x) - f(x)|dx$

After some steps I find

$\mathbb{E} [ |\mathbb{E}[f|F_n] - f| ] \leq \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 2^n \int_{I_{k,n}^2} |f(x)-f(y)|dydx $ but I can't find a way to show that this term goes to zero as n goes to infinity. Maybe I have been to brutal on the majoration. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you familiar with a) martingale convergence theorems and/or b) uniform integrability/Vitali's convergence theorem?

Comment: Yes, I can use this approach, $g_n$ is a uniformly integrable martingale thus it converges a.s and in $L^1$ but how do I prove that the limit is f ?

Comment: Since we know that the limit exists (almost surely and in $L^1$), it suffices to identify the limit. Set $g := \lim_n g_n$. As $$\forall F \in F_n: \quad \int_F g_k \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F f \, d\mathbb{P}$$ for all $k \geq n$, it follows from the $L^1$-convergence that $$\forall F \in F_n: \quad \int_F g \, d\mathbb{P}= \int_F f \, d\mathbb{P}. $$ Conclude that $$\forall F \in \mathcal{B}: \quad \int_F g \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F f \, d\mathbb{P}$$ where $\mathcal{B}= \sigma(F_n; n \geq 1)$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

Comment: Finally use the fact that $f$ is (by assumption) Borel-measurable to conclude that $f=g$ almost surely.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you for you help.